# Updates kill Keyboard and mouse

Tags: updates, keyboard, mouse

I had applied all the updates available for on 23rd Morning and Keyboard and mouse stopped working thereafter. The updates amounted to around 230 MBs in size. I can use the keyboard to select other items in Grub menu and it works upto the login prompt. I can change the console to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> during boot up before the login screen. No response thereafter. I have set the autoloin after 10 Seconds and also the notification asks me for enabling compositing.

Some thread advises me to remove the **.gconfd** folder of my home. Please advise whether it is safe. I have done some customizations in Ubuntu. will they be lost?

When booted in recovery mode, the screen remains blank without the options like Repair Packages, Root shell, Resume etc. BTW, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> reboots the blank screen.

What to do now? I thought that Recovery mode boot will give me the menu of these above items.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively safe way to test the "something in `.gconf` doesn't like me" hypothesis is

```
cd
mv .gconf dot.gconf
```

where the obvious inverse

```
mv dot.gconf .gconf
```

will set things back to the way they were if this doesn't help. Also useful for testing this hypothesis is to `adduser` a dummy account and see if a fresh user is also so afflicted.

Incidentally `.gconfd` contains very little information, perhaps you misread the original recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

My issue seems similar enough to post here, although my keyboard (and mouse) do not work at the login screen at all.

I had `apt upgrade`d, and while the box booted to the lightdm login screen, keyboard and mouse were non-responsive (laptop internal, also I tried plugging in usb).  After a time the cursor in the password field stopped blinking as well.

It appears some X packages had been incorrectly deleted when i ran an `apt autoremove` (necessary due to a full /boot drive).

re-installing `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` fixed the issue for me.

(to install this, boot into recovery mode, enable networking, and drop into the root shell.  When completed, reboot.)